# sliding panels from offscreen

Tags: html, css

I have an idea where I have a brain in the middle of the page and if they click the left brain the content would slide right revealing a new page on the left and if they click on the right brain the content would scroll/slide left and you would see the page offscreen to the right.

I have a mock up of the full width here if you manually horizontally scroll. For the real thing I don't want the user to be able to scroll but the JS to handle that.

http://shawnwow.com/revised/

I am figuring I can just offset the site -100vw initially and if they choose left side then its offset by 0 and its the right it would be offset by -200vw. I can probably figure out the jQuery to change the class but having some issues getting the CSS to work.

Here is the code base if that helps.

https://github.com/shellwe/shawnwow/tree/2018-site-revision

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How would I make it so that I can have it show just the middle screen, with the brain on it, and not allow the user to scroll left or right but then have the left and right divs offsreen and scroll over to them with the JS, but not allow them to manually horizontally scroll

Comment: To confirm, was I being downvoted because I was too wordy or didn't provide a fiddle as an example? 
I would prefer not to be banned for 6 months so knowing why would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddleJS -  https://jsfiddle.net/darrendiscovr/79kh2cq1/. Snippet below shows the result but to keep within the character limit I minified the code. See the fiddleJS for unminified.

This could be a good starting point. I think your page would be much better served like this, using the main content with panels that slide left or right.

I have currently only had the time to overlap the panels, but you should easily be able to extend this by adding Jquery `addClass` to the main page content to push with the sliding panels.

Where credit is due, I used [Codyhouse](https://codyhouse.co/) to replicate your page using one of their demonstrations of sliding panels. It is a great tool when looking for inspiration to JS and CSS transitions. I also recommend [Codrops](https://tympanus.net/codrops/) as a source of inspiration.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.right-brain-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.right-brain-panel').addClass('is-visible');
  });
  $('.right-brain-panel').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.right-brain-panel') || $(event.target).is('.closebrain')) {
      $('.right-brain-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  $('.left-brain-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.left-brain-panel').addClass('is-visible');
  });
  $('.left-brain-panel').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('.left-brain-panel') || $(event.target).is('.closebrain')) {
      $('.left-brain-panel').removeClass('is-visible');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{margin: 0;}#center-page{height: 100vh; width: 100vw; display: flex; align-items: center;}#center-page>div{flex: 0 1 auto; width: 50%;}#center-page #left-side{background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25); transition: background-color 1s;}#center-page #left-side:hover{background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 1s;}#center-page #left-side #left-brain svg{margin-left: auto; margin-right: 1%;}#center-page #left-side #left-brain svg *{fill: red;}#center-page #right-side{background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.25); transition: background-color 1s;}#center-page #right-side:hover{background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5); transition: background-color 1s;}#center-page #right-side #right-brain svg{margin-left: 1%; margin-right: auto;}#center-page #right-side #right-brain svg *{fill: blue;}#center-page .either-side:hover .brain-image svg{height: 85%; transition: height 1s;}#center-page .brain-image{height: 100vh; display: flex; align-items: center;}#center-page .brain-image svg{height: 75%; transition: height 1s;}#center-page .brain-image svg *{width: 100%; height: 100%;}.right-brain-panel{position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; visibility: hidden; -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s; -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s; transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;}.right-brain-panel::after{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: transparent; cursor: pointer; -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s; -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s; transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;}.right-brain-panel.is-visible{visibility: visible; -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s; -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s; transition: visibility 0s 0s;}.right-brain-panel.is-visible::after{background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0s; -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0s; transition: background 0.3s 0s;}.left-brain-panel{position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; visibility: hidden; -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s; -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s; transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;}.left-brain-panel::after{position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: transparent; cursor: pointer; -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s; -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s; transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;}.left-brain-panel.is-visible{visibility: visible; -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s; -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s; transition: visibility 0s 0s;}.left-brain-panel.is-visible::after{background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0s; -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0s; transition: background 0.3s 0s;}.brain-container{position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; background: #dbe2e9; z-index: 1; -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform; -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform; transition-property: transform; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s; -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s; transition-duration: 0.3s; -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s; -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s; transition-delay: 0.3s;}.from-right .brain-container{right: 0; background: #c8c4fc; -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0); -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0); -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0); -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);}.from-left .brain-container{left: 0; background: #f5c3c1; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);}.is-visible .brain-container{-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -webkit-transition-delay: 0s; -moz-transition-delay: 0s; transition-delay: 0s;}.brain-content{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 70px 5%; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div id="center-page"> <div id="left-side" class="either-side"> <a href="#0" data-move="left" class="left-brain-btn"> <div id="left-brain" class="brain-image"> <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 22.3 51.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 22.3 51.2;" xml:space="preserve"><g><path d="M10.7,39.1c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.3,1c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7s0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.6-0.6,0.9-1.3,0.9-2.1c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.4-1.5l0.3-0.2c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7s-0.5-0.2-0.7,0l-0.2,0.2c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.4-1.2,0.4l-0.2,0l-0.2,0c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9-0.5c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.3-1c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.5-1.3l0,0c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7l0,0l0,0c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7,0l0,0c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.5-1.3,0.5c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.4-0.6s-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7s-0.5-0.2-0.7,0c-0.6,0.6-0.9,1.3-0.9,2.1c0,0.7,0.3,1.5,0.9,2.1c0.6,0.6,1.3,0.9,2.1,0.9c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.5-0.1c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.5c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.4,1.5c0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.6l0.2,0.2c0.5,0.5,1.2,0.7,1.9,0.7C10.1,39.2,10.4,39.2,10.7,39.1z"></path><path d="M21.8,3.5c-0.9-2.1-3-3.5-5.3-3.5c-1.3,0-2.5,0.4-3.5,1.1l0,0c0,0-3.3,2.5-6.5,7.4C6.2,8.9,5.9,9.3,5.7,9.8l0,0.1c-1.4,2.3-2.7,5-3.8,8.2c-0.2,0.5-0.3,0.9-0.4,1.4c-0.5,1.6-0.8,3.4-1.1,5.3c-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.9-0.2,1.4c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.1,1.5c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3C0,28.7,0,29.5,0,30.3c0,0.7,0,1.5,0.1,2.3l0,0l0,0.1c0,0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1.1l0,0c0.4,2.6,1.5,6.9,4.3,10.7c0.9,1.2,2,2.4,3.3,3.4C8,47.9,8.1,48,8.3,48.2C8.2,48.1,8.1,48,8,47.9c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3l0,0l0.1,0.1l0,0l0,0l0.1,0l0.1,0l-0.1,0c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2l-0.1,0l-0.1-0.1c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.2c2.5,1.6,5.8,2.7,9.8,2.7c1,0,1.9-0.4,2.5-1c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.5-0.7v0c0,0,0.5-0.8,0.5-1.5s0-35.5,0-35.5s0.1-5.6,0.1-6.6C22.4,4.4,21.8,3.5,21.8,3.5z M8.9,6.9c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.7-0.2,1c0,0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6-0.1c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0C8.1,7.9,8.5,7.4,8.9,6.9z M5.4,12.3c0.1,0.4,0.4,0.8,0.7,1.1c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0s0.2-0.5,0-0.7c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4c0-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.3-1l0-0.1c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6c0.5,0,1,0.2,1.4,0.6l0.2,0.1c0.5,0.4,1.2,0.7,1.9,0.7c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5s-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5c-1.1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-1.1,0.9-1.9,1.9-1.9c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5S11.9,5,11.6,5C11,5,10.5,5.2,10,5.5c0.6-0.7,1.1-1.3,1.6-1.8c0.6-0.6,1.1-1.1,1.4-1.4c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.3L13.5,2l0,0c0.5-0.3,1-0.6,1.6-0.8c-0.4,0.5-0.7,1.1-0.7,1.8v0c-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.4-1.4-0.4c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5s0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5c1,0,1.8,0.8,1.8,1.8c0,1-0.8,1.8-1.8,1.8l-0.2,0c-0.4,0.1-0.9,0.3-1.2,0.6c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7s0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.3-0.3,0.6-0.4,1-0.4s0.7,0.1,1,0.4s0.4,0.6,0.4,1s-0.1,0.7-0.4,1c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.7,0.6-1.1c0.5,0.4,1.1,0.6,1.7,0.6c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5s-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5c-1.1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-1.1,0.9-1.9,1.9-1.9c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5s-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5c-1.1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-1.1,0.9-1.9,1.9-1.9l0,0c0.9,0.2,1.8,0.7,2.4,1.3c0.9,0.9,1.4,2.1,1.4,3.4V12l0,0.1v0c0,1.2-1,2.2-2.2,2.2h0l-0.2,0.1c-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.3,0.5c0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5v0c1.2,0,2.2,1,2.2,2.2c0,1.2-1,2.2-2.2,2.2h0c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5v0h0l0,0c0.9,0,1.7-0.4,2.3-1v0.9v4.3v0.4c-0.4-1-1.4-1.7-2.6-1.7c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5s0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5c1,0,1.8,0.8,1.8,1.8c0,1-0.8,1.8-1.8,1.8c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5s0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5c1.2,0,2.2-0.7,2.6-1.7v1.3v0.6v0.1c-0.1,1.1-1,2.1-2.2,2.1c-1.2,0-2.2-1-2.2-2.2l0,0l0,0c0-1.6-1.3-2.9-2.9-2.9c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8c0-0.6-0.2-1.1-0.5-1.6c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.5-0.8c0.2-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.2-1.2c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5l0-0.1c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c0-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.4-1.2c0,1,0.5,1.8,1.2,2.3c-0.7,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.2,2.1c0,1.4,1.1,2.5,2.5,2.5c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5S17.3,26,17,26c-0.8,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5l0.2-0.1l0.1,0c0.2,0,0.4-0.2,0.5-0.4l0-0.1c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5c-1.1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-1,0.8-1.9,1.9-1.9l0,0c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5v0l0,0c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5l0,0c-1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-1.1,0.9-1.9,1.9-1.9h0c1.6,0,2.9-1.3,2.9-2.9c0-1-0.5-1.9-1.3-2.4c0.8-0.5,1.3-1.4,1.3-2.4c0-1.6-1.3-2.9-2.9-2.9c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5s0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5c1.1,0,1.9,0.9,1.9,1.9c0,1.1-0.9,1.9-1.9,1.9c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5l0,0h0c1.1,0,1.9,0.9,1.9,1.9c0,1.1-0.9,1.9-1.9,1.9h0c-0.9,0-1.6,0.4-2.2,1c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6-0.8c-0.6-0.6-1.3-0.9-2.1-0.9c-0.6,0-1.3,0.2-1.8,0.6c-0.1-0.4-0.4-0.8-0.7-1.1c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7,0s-0.2,0.5,0,0.7c0.4,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4s-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.4-0.6l-0.1,0C6.3,14.4,6.2,14.2,6,14c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7,0s-0.2,0.5,0,0.7c0.3,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.5,1.2c0,0.4-0.2,0.8-0.5,1.2c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7s0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3l0.1-0.1c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6s1,0.2,1.4,0.6c0.4,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4s-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7l0,0l0,0c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6s1,0.2,1.4,0.6c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.5,1l0,0.1c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3c0,0.4-0.2,0.9-0.5,1.2c-0.5-0.4-1.1-0.6-1.7-0.6c-0.4,0-0.9,0.1-1.3,0.3c-0.1-0.5-0.4-1-0.8-1.4c-0.6-0.6-1.3-0.9-2.1-0.9c-0.3,0-0.5,0.1-0.8,0.1l0-0.2c0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.2-1l0.2,0c0.7,0,1.4-0.3,2-0.8c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7s-0.5-0.2-0.7,0c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.5-1.3,0.5s-0.9-0.2-1.3-0.5c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.1c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.3-1.3-0.3l0,0C3.7,15.8,4.5,14,5.4,12.3z M9.8,16.6C9.6,16.3,9.3,16.2,9,16c0.4-0.1,0.8-0.4,1.1-0.7c0.6-0.6,0.9-1.4,0.9-2.2l0,0l0.2-0.1c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6s1,0.2,1.4,0.6c0.4,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.7-0.3,1c-0.5-0.4-1.1-0.6-1.7-0.5c-0.7,0-1.5,0.3-2.1,0.9c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7s0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6s1,0.2,1.4,0.6s0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.5,1.3l0,0c-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.6-0.6,0.9l0,0c-0.6-0.6-1.3-0.9-2.1-0.9c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0.1c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6C10.7,17.9,10.4,17.2,9.8,16.6z M15.4,17.2c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.2v0C15.4,17.6,15.4,17.4,15.4,17.2z M1.3,25.1c0.3-0.6,1-1.1,1.7-1.1C4.1,24,5,24.8,5,25.9c0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5S6,26.2,6,25.9C6,24.3,4.7,23,3.1,23c-0.5,0-1,0.2-1.5,0.4c0.3-1.6,0.7-3.1,1.1-4.5c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.4,0c0.5,0,1,0.2,1.4,0.6C4.8,19.7,5,20.2,5,20.7c0,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.8l-0.1,0.1c-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.3l-0.2,0.2c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7s0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.4-0.6c0.4-0.3,0.8-0.4,1.2-0.4c0.5,0,1,0.2,1.4,0.6c0.4,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7s0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.4-0.4,0.7-1,0.8-1.5c0.4-0.3,0.8-0.5,1.3-0.5c0.5,0,1,0.2,1.4,0.6c0.4,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4s-0.2,1-0.6,1.4l-0.1,0.1c-0.7,0.5-1.1,1.3-1.1,2.3c0,1.1-0.9,1.9-1.9,1.9c-0.9,0-1.7-0.6-1.9-1.5c1.3-0.3,2.4-1.4,2.4-2.9c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5s-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,1.1-0.9,1.9-1.9,1.9c-1.1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5s-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,0.6,0.2,1.1,0.5,1.6c-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.2-1.1,0.4c-0.4-0.8-1.1-1.4-2.1-1.6C1.2,26.6,1.2,25.8,1.3,25.1z M7.8,31.9l-0.1,0l0-0.1L7.8,31.9z M1,30.3c0-0.7,0-1.3,0-1.9c0.8,0.2,1.4,1,1.4,1.8c0,0.9-0.6,1.6-1.4,1.8C1,31.4,1,30.9,1,30.3z M7.2,42.5c0,0.6,0.2,1.2,0.5,1.6c-0.4,0.5-0.6,1.1-0.6,1.7l0,0.1c-0.7-0.7-1.3-1.4-1.9-2.1c-1-1.3-1.8-2.7-2.4-4.1c0.4-0.3,0.8-0.5,1.3-0.5c0.5,0,1,0.2,1.4,0.6c0.4,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7s0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.6-0.6,0.9-1.3,0.9-2.1c0-0.7-0.3-1.5-0.9-2.1c-0.6-0.6-1.3-0.9-2.1-0.9c-0.6,0-1.2,0.2-1.7,0.6c-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.9-0.5-1.4c0.4,0.2,0.8,0.3,1.2,0.3c0.7,0,1.5-0.3,2.1-0.9c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7s-0.5-0.2-0.7,0c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.4-0.6c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9c-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.2-1c0-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6c0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.7-0.3L2,32.7c0.9-0.5,1.4-1.4,1.4-2.5l0-0.2c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.5,1.3-0.5c0.5,0,1,0.2,1.4,0.6s0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.5,1.3l0,0c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7l0,0l0,0c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0l0,0c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.5,1.3-0.5c0.5,0,1,0.2,1.4,0.6c0.4,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.8c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.6l-0.1,0.1c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.4,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.4,0.4c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.7-0.6c0,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.4,1.2c-0.4,0.5-0.6,1.1-0.6,1.8c0,0.6,0.2,1.2,0.5,1.6c-0.4,0.5-0.6,1.1-0.6,1.7c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.9c-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.2-1-0.2c-0.7,0-1.4,0.3-1.9,0.8l-0.1,0c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.4-0.6c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7s-0.5-0.2-0.7,0C7.5,41,7.2,41.7,7.2,42.5z M11,48.6c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.2c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5C11.4,48.8,11.2,48.7,11,48.6z M14.2,49.4c-1.1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5c-0.2,0-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.2c-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.3,0.5c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.3l-0.1,0c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4c0-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.3-1c0.5,0.4,1.1,0.6,1.7,0.6c0.7,0,1.4-0.3,1.9-0.8l0.1,0c0.5,0,1,0.2,1.4,0.6c0.4,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4s-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7s0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.6-0.6,0.9-1.3,0.9-2.1c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.2c0.7,0,1.4-0.3,1.9-0.7c0.5,0.4,1,0.6,1.6,0.7c0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.5c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6-0.1c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5s-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5l0,0.1c0,0.4-0.1,0.7-0.3,1C15.4,49.1,14.8,49.4,14.2,49.4z M17.3,41c-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.3,0.5c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.4-0.6c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4c0-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.3-1c0.5,0.5,1.2,0.7,1.9,0.7c0.2,0,0.5,0,0.7-0.1c0,0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4C16.9,40.1,17.1,40.5,17.3,41z M14.3,41.9c0.5,0.4,1.1,0.6,1.7,0.6c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.9-0.2c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.6c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.4,1.4c-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.3,0.5c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.4-0.6c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4C14,42.6,14.1,42.2,14.3,41.9z M21.3,44.2v1.2v2.3c0,0.7-0.3,1.3-0.7,1.8c-0.4,0.5-1.1,0.7-1.8,0.7c-1.1,0-2.1-0.1-3-0.2c0.4-0.2,0.7-0.6,1-1c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.9,0.2c0.7,0,1.5-0.3,2.1-0.9s0.9-1.3,0.9-2.1c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.5c-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.9c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c-0.3,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4c0-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.3-1c0.5,0.4,1.1,0.6,1.7,0.6c0.5,0,1-0.1,1.4-0.4L21.3,44.2L21.3,44.2z M21.3,40.9L21.3,40.9L21.3,40.9c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6s-1-0.2-1.4-0.6c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7s-0.5-0.2-0.7,0l-0.2,0.2l0,0c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6s-1-0.2-1.4-0.6c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4c0-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.3-1.1c0.6,0.4,1.3,0.6,2,0.6c0.1,0,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.2l0.1-0.1c0.4-0.4,1-0.7,1.6-0.7s1.1,0.2,1.6,0.7c0.4,0.4,0.7,1,0.7,1.6c0,0.6-0.2,1.1-0.7,1.6c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7s0.5,0.2,0.7,0l0.2-0.3h0V40.9z M21.3,35.2L21,35c-0.6-0.6-1.5-0.9-2.3-0.9c-0.8,0-1.6,0.3-2.2,0.9c-1-0.1-1.8-0.6-2.2-1.5c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3c0.7-0.2,1.2-0.9,1.2-1.7c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5s-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,0.8c-0.4,0-0.8-0.4-0.8-0.8c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5s-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,0.7,0.4,1.3,1,1.6L13,33c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.6c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4c0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4s-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.2c0.2-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.3-1.3c0-0.7-0.3-1.5-0.9-2.1c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.7-0.5c1.4-0.2,2.5-1.4,2.5-2.9c0-1.1,0.9-1.9,1.9-1.9c1.1,0,1.9,0.9,1.9,1.9l0,0l0,0c0,1.7,1.4,3.2,3.2,3.2c0.8,0,1.6-0.3,2.2-0.9h0L21.3,35.2L21.3,35.2z M21.3,15.3L21.3,15.3c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.5c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.5-0.4l0.1-0.1V15.3z"></path></g></svg> </div></a> </div><div id="right-side" class="either-side"> <a href="#0" data-move="right" class="right-brain-btn"> <div id="right-brain" class="brain-image"> <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 22.3 51.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 22.3 51.2;" xml:space="preserve"><g><path d="M11.7,39.1c-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.3,1c0,0.5,0.2,1,0.6,1.4c0.2,0.2,0.2,0.5,0,0.7s-0.5,0.2-0.7,0c-0.6-0.6-0.9-1.3-0.9-2.1 c0-0.5,0.1-1,0.4-1.5l-0.3-0.2c-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.5,0-0.7s0.5-0.2,0.7,0l0.2,0.2c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.4,1.2,0.4l0.2,0l0.2,0 c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9-0.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4c0.2-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.3-1c0-0.5-0.2-1-0.5-1.3l0,0c-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.5,0-0.7l0,0l0,0 c0.2-0.2,0.5-0.2,0.7,0l0,0c0.4,0.4,0.8,0.5,1.3,0.5c0.5,0,1-0.2,1.4-0.6s0.6-0.9,0.6-1.4c0-0.5-0.2-1-0.6-1.4 c-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.5,0-0.7s0.5-0.2,0.7,0c0.6,0.6,0.9,1.3,0.9,2.1c0,0.7-0.3,1.5-0.9,2.1s-1.3,0.9-2.1,0.9c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.5-0.1 c0,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.4,1.5c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.4,0.6l-0.2,0.2c-0.5,0.5-1.2,0.7-1.9,0.7 C12.3,39.2,12,39.2,11.7,39.1z"></path><path d="M0,5.9c0,1,0.1,6.6,0.1,6.6s0,34.8,0,35.5s0.5,1.5,0.5,1.5v0c0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.5,0.7c0.6,0.6,1.5,1,2.5,1 c4.1,0,7.3-1,9.8-2.7c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.2l-0.1,0.1l-0.1,0c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2l-0.1,0l0.1,0l0.1,0l0,0l0,0l0.1-0.1l0,0 c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.5-0.4c1.3-1,2.4-2.1,3.3-3.4c2.8-3.7,3.9-8,4.3-10.7l0,0 c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-1.1l0-0.1l0,0c0-0.8,0.1-1.5,0.1-2.3c0-0.8,0-1.6-0.1-2.4c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.1-1.5 c0-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.2-1.4c-0.3-1.9-0.6-3.6-1.1-5.3c-0.1-0.5-0.3-1-0.4-1.4c-1-3.2-2.4-5.9-3.8-8.2l0-0.1c-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.8-0.8-1.2 c-3.2-4.9-6.5-7.4-6.5-7.4l0,0C8.4,0.4,7.2,0,5.9,0C3.5,0,1.5,1.4,0.6,3.5C0.6,3.5,0,4.4,0,5.9z M14.6,8.5c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0 c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.6,0.1c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6c0-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.2-1C13.9,7.4,14.3,7.9,14.6,8.5z M19.3,17.8L19.3,17.8 c-0.5,0-0.9,0.1-1.3,0.3c-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4,0.1c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.5-1.3,0.5c-0.5,0-0.9-0.2-1.3-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7,0 s-0.2,0.5,0,0.7c0.5,0.5,1.3,0.8,2,0.8l0.2,0c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.2,1l0,0.2c-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.8-0.1c-0.7,0-1.5,0.3-2.1,0.9 c-0.4,0.4-0.7,0.9-0.8,1.4c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.3-1.3-0.3c-0.6,0-1.2,0.2-1.7,0.6c-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.8-0.5-1.2c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3l0-0.1 c0.1-0.4,0.2-0.7,0.5-1c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6s1,0.2,1.4,0.6c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0v0l0,0c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7 c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4s0.2-1,0.6-1.4c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6c0.5,0,1,0.2,1.4,0.6l0.1,0.1c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3 c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0s0.2-0.5,0-0.7c-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.7-0.5-1.2c0-0.4,0.2-0.8,0.5-1.2c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7s-0.5-0.2-0.7,0 c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4-0.4,0.6l-0.1,0c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.4-0.6c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4s0.2-1,0.6-1.4 c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7s-0.5-0.2-0.7,0c-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.7-0.7,1.1c-0.5-0.4-1.2-0.6-1.8-0.6c-0.7,0-1.5,0.3-2.1,0.9 c-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.5-0.6,0.8c-0.5-0.6-1.3-1-2.2-1h0c-1.1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-1.1,0.9-1.9,1.9-1.9l0,0l0,0c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5 S5.3,7.4,5,7.4c-1.1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-1.1,0.9-1.9,1.9-1.9c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5S5.3,2.5,5,2.5c-1.6,0-2.9,1.3-2.9,2.9 c0,1,0.5,1.9,1.3,2.4c-0.8,0.5-1.3,1.4-1.3,2.4c0,1.6,1.3,2.9,2.9,2.9h0c1.1,0,1.9,0.9,1.9,1.9c0,1-0.8,1.9-1.9,1.9l0,0 c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5l0,0v0C4.5,17.8,4.7,18,5,18l0,0c1,0,1.9,0.9,1.9,1.9C6.9,21,6,21.9,5,21.9c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5l0,0.1 c0,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.4l0.1,0l0.2,0.1c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5c0,0.8-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5S5,27,5.3,27 c1.4,0,2.5-1.1,2.5-2.5c0-0.9-0.5-1.7-1.2-2.1c0.7-0.5,1.2-1.4,1.2-2.3c0.3,0.4,0.4,0.8,0.4,1.2c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3l0,0.1 c0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.5c0,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2C8.6,23.5,8.8,23.8,9,24c-0.3,0.5-0.5,1-0.5,1.6c0,0.3,0.1,0.5,0.1,0.8 c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0c-1.6,0-2.9,1.3-2.9,2.9l0,0l0,0c0,1.2-1,2.2-2.2,2.2c-1.2,0-2.1-0.9-2.2-2.1v-0.1v-0.6v-1.3 c0.4,1,1.4,1.7,2.6,1.7c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5s-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5c-1,0-1.8-0.8-1.8-1.8c0-1,0.8-1.8,1.8-1.8c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5 s-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5c-1.2,0-2.2,0.7-2.6,1.7v-0.4v-4.3v-0.9c0.6,0.6,1.4,1,2.3,1l0,0h0v0c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5 c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5h0c-1.2,0-2.2-1-2.2-2.2c0-1.2,1-2.2,2.2-2.2v0c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5c0-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.5l-0.2-0.1h0 c-1.2,0-2.2-1-2.2-2.2v0l0-0.1V5.8c0-1.3,0.5-2.5,1.4-3.4C3.2,1.8,4,1.3,4.9,1.1l0,0C6,1.1,6.9,2,6.9,3C6.9,4.1,6,4.9,5,4.9 c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5S4.7,5.9,5,5.9c1.1,0,1.9,0.9,1.9,1.9C6.9,8.9,6,9.8,5,9.8c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5s0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5 c0.7,0,1.2-0.2,1.7-0.6C6.8,10.6,7,11,7.3,11.3c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.4-1s0.1-0.7,0.4-1 s0.6-0.4,1-0.4c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.4c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0s0.2-0.5,0-0.7c-0.3-0.3-0.8-0.6-1.2-0.6l-0.2,0c-1,0-1.8-0.8-1.8-1.8 c0-1,0.8-1.8,1.8-1.8c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5S9.5,2.6,9.3,2.6c-0.5,0-1,0.1-1.4,0.4v0c0-0.7-0.3-1.3-0.7-1.8 c0.6,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.6,0.8l0,0L8.9,2C9,2.1,9.2,2.2,9.3,2.4c0.3,0.3,0.8,0.8,1.4,1.4c0.5,0.5,1,1.1,1.6,1.8c-0.5-0.3-1-0.5-1.6-0.5 c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5S10.5,6,10.8,6c1.1,0,1.9,0.9,1.9,1.9c0,1.1-0.9,1.9-1.9,1.9c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5s0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5 c0.7,0,1.4-0.3,1.9-0.7l0.2-0.1c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6s1,0.2,1.4,0.6c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3l0,0.1c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.3,1 c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.5,0,0.7s0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.3-0.3,0.5-0.7,0.7-1.1C17.8,14,18.6,15.8,19.3,17.8z M11.7,18.7 c0,0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6c-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6-0.1c-0.7,0-1.5,0.3-2.1,0.9l0,0c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6-0.9l0,0c-0.4-0.4-0.5-0.9-0.5-1.3 c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4s0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6s1,0.2,1.4,0.6c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0s0.2-0.5,0-0.7c-0.6-0.6-1.3-0.9-2.1-0.9 c-0.6,0-1.2,0.2-1.7,0.5c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.3-1c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6s1,0.2,1.4,0.6l0.2,0.1l0,0 c0,0.8,0.3,1.6,0.9,2.2c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.5,1.1,0.7c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.3-0.8,0.6C11.9,17.2,11.7,17.9,11.7,18.7z M6.9,17.8L6.9,17.8 c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3C6.9,17.4,6.9,17.6,6.9,17.8z M21.2,27.3c-0.9,0.2-1.7,0.8-2.1,1.6 c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.4-1.1-0.4c0.3-0.5,0.5-1,0.5-1.6c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,1.1-0.9,1.9-1.9,1.9 c-1.1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,1.4,1,2.6,2.4,2.9c-0.2,0.8-1,1.5-1.9,1.5 c-1.1,0-1.9-0.9-1.9-1.9c0-0.9-0.4-1.7-1.1-2.3L10.1,27c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4s0.2-1,0.6-1.4c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6 c0.5,0,0.9,0.2,1.3,0.5c0.1,0.6,0.4,1.1,0.8,1.5c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0s0.2-0.5,0-0.7c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4 c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6c0.4,0,0.9,0.2,1.2,0.4c0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.6c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0s0.2-0.5,0-0.7 l-0.2-0.2c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3l-0.1-0.1c-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.2-0.8c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6 c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.4,0c0.4,1.4,0.8,2.9,1.1,4.5c-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.4-1.5-0.4c-1.6,0-2.9,1.3-2.9,2.9c0,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5 c0.3,0,0.5-0.2,0.5-0.5c0-1.1,0.9-1.9,1.9-1.9c0.8,0,1.4,0.4,1.7,1.1C21.1,25.8,21.2,26.6,21.2,27.3z M14.7,31.8L14.7,31.8 l-0.1,0.1L14.7,31.8z M21.3,32c-0.8-0.2-1.4-1-1.4-1.8c0-0.9,0.6-1.6,1.4-1.8c0,0.6,0,1.3,0,1.9C21.3,30.9,21.3,31.4,21.3,32zM14.3,40.4c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7,0s-0.2,0.5,0,0.7c0.4,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4s-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6l-0.1,0 c-0.6-0.5-1.2-0.8-1.9-0.8c-0.3,0-0.7,0.1-1,0.2c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-0.9c0-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.6-1.7c0.3-0.5,0.5-1.1,0.5-1.6 c0-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.6-1.8C8.9,37.4,9,37,9,36.6c0.5,0.4,1.1,0.6,1.7,0.6c0.5,0,1-0.1,1.4-0.4c0.2,0.1,0.5,0.1,0.7,0 c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.1-0.6l-0.1-0.1c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.6c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.8c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4 c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6c0.5,0,1,0.2,1.3,0.5l0,0c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0l0,0l0,0c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7l0,0 c-0.4-0.4-0.5-0.8-0.5-1.3c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4s0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6c0.5,0,0.9,0.2,1.3,0.5l0,0.2c0,1.1,0.6,2,1.4,2.5l0.2,0.1 c0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.7,0.3c0,0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6c0,0.3-0.1,0.7-0.2,1c-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5 c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.4-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7,0s-0.2,0.5,0,0.7c0.6,0.6,1.3,0.9,2.1,0.9 c0.4,0,0.8-0.1,1.2-0.3c-0.1,0.5-0.3,0.9-0.5,1.4c-0.5-0.4-1.1-0.6-1.7-0.6c-0.7,0-1.5,0.3-2.1,0.9c-0.6,0.6-0.9,1.3-0.9,2.1 c0,0.7,0.3,1.5,0.9,2.1c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0s0.2-0.5,0-0.7c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4c0-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4 c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6c0.5,0,0.9,0.2,1.3,0.5c-0.6,1.4-1.4,2.8-2.4,4.1c-0.6,0.7-1.2,1.4-1.9,2.1l0-0.1c0-0.6-0.2-1.2-0.6-1.7 c0.3-0.5,0.5-1.1,0.5-1.6C15.2,41.7,14.9,41,14.3,40.4z M10.7,48.9c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2 C11.2,48.7,11,48.8,10.7,48.9z M6.6,48.6c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.3-1l0-0.1C6.3,47.2,6,47,5.8,47c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5 c0,0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.6c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.4-0.6c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4c0-0.2,0-0.3,0.1-0.5 c0.6-0.1,1.1-0.3,1.6-0.7c0.5,0.5,1.2,0.7,1.9,0.7c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.2c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.2,0.9c0,0.7,0.3,1.5,0.9,2.1 c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0s0.2-0.5,0-0.7c-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4s0.2-1,0.6-1.4c0.4-0.4,0.9-0.6,1.4-0.6l0.1,0 c0.6,0.5,1.2,0.8,1.9,0.8c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.7-0.6c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.3,1c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.2l-0.1,0 c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.3c-0.5,0-0.9-0.2-1.3-0.5c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.2c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,1.1-0.9,1.9-1.9,1.9 C7.5,49.4,6.9,49.1,6.6,48.6z M5.4,39.6c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4c0.2,0.1,0.5,0.1,0.7,0.1c0.7,0,1.3-0.2,1.9-0.7c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.3,1 c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6c-0.5,0-0.9-0.2-1.3-0.5C5.3,40.5,5.4,40.1,5.4,39.6z M8.3,42.9c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4 s-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6c-0.5,0-0.9-0.2-1.3-0.5c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.4-1.4c0-0.2,0-0.4-0.1-0.6c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.2,0.9,0.2 c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.7-0.6C8.2,42.2,8.3,42.6,8.3,42.9z M1.1,42.1c0.4,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.4,0.4c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.7-0.6 c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.3,1c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3c-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.3-1,0.3c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3,0 c-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.6-0.4,0.9c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.5c0,0.7,0.3,1.5,0.9,2.1s1.3,0.9,2.1,0.9c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.9-0.2 c0.2,0.4,0.6,0.7,1,1c-1,0.1-2,0.2-3,0.2c-0.8,0-1.4-0.3-1.8-0.7c-0.4-0.5-0.7-1.1-0.7-1.8v-2.3v-1.2C1.1,44.2,1.1,42.1,1.1,42.1zM1.1,39.3L1.1,39.3l0.2,0.3c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,0.7,0c0.2-0.2,0.2-0.5,0-0.7c-0.4-0.4-0.7-1-0.7-1.6c0-0.6,0.2-1.1,0.7-1.6 c0.4-0.4,1-0.7,1.6-0.7s1.1,0.2,1.6,0.7l0.1,0.1C5.4,35.9,5.5,36,5.7,36c0.8,0,1.5-0.2,2-0.6C7.9,35.6,8,36,8,36.4 c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6s-1-0.2-1.4-0.6l0,0l-0.2-0.2c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.2-0.7,0s-0.2,0.5,0,0.7 c0.4,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.6,1.4s-0.2,1-0.6,1.4c-0.4,0.4-0.9,0.6-1.4,0.6s-1-0.2-1.4-0.6l0,0l0-0.1V39.3z M1.1,31.7L1.1,31.7 c0.6,0.5,1.3,0.9,2.2,0.9c1.7,0,3.2-1.4,3.2-3.2l0,0l0,0c0-1.1,0.9-1.9,1.9-1.9c1.1,0,1.9,0.9,1.9,1.9c0,1.5,1.1,2.7,2.5,2.9 c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.7,0.5c-0.6,0.6-0.9,1.3-0.9,2.1c0,0.4,0.1,0.9,0.3,1.3c-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.8,0.2c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.4-0.6 s-0.6-0.9-0.6-1.4c0-0.2,0-0.3,0.1-0.4C8.9,33.8,9,33.6,9,33.5c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.6l0.1-0.2c0.6-0.3,1-0.9,1-1.6 c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,0.8c-0.4,0-0.8-0.4-0.8-0.8c0-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.5-0.5 c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.5,0.5c0,0.8,0.5,1.5,1.2,1.7c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3C8,33.2,8,33.3,8,33.5c-0.4,0.8-1.2,1.4-2.2,1.5 c-0.6-0.6-1.4-0.9-2.2-0.9c-0.8,0-1.7,0.3-2.3,0.9l-0.2,0.2L1.1,31.7L1.1,31.7z M1.1,14.4L1.1,14.4c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.5 c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.3-0.6,0.5l0,0V14.4z"></path></g></svg> </div></a> </div></div><div class="right-brain-panel from-right"> <div class="brain-container"> <div class="brain-content"> <h1>This is the content of the right brain panel!!!!!</h1> <form action="https://formspree.io/shellwe@gmail.com" method="POST"> <input type="text" name="name"> <input type="email" name="_replyto"> <input type="submit" value="Send"> </form> <a href="#0" class="closebrain">Back</a> </div></div></div><div class="left-brain-panel from-left"> <div class="brain-container"> <div class="brain-content"> <h1>This is the content of the left brain panel!!!!!</h1> <form action="https://formspree.io/shellwe@gmail.com" method="POST"> <input type="text" name="name"> <input type="email" name="_replyto"> <input type="submit" value="Send"> </form> <a href="#0" class="closebrain">Back</a> </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the time to do that! This looks neat! I ended up just having a container with 300vw width in a 100vw body with overflow set to hidden and then I would set the container between 0 and -200vw to show the sections. While what I did works I will check this out too and see if it is a better fit for me.